# problemas com o jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Galera estou usando o jQuery-Mask-Plugin para criar mascaras nos campos de valores, gostei dele pois e muito simples.

O problema e quando tento adicionar um valor negativo ele não aceita o -. Porém revirei a internet e achei uma forma dele aceitar. O problema e que ele não esta formatando o campo de forma correta.

Irei posto o código no JSFIDDLE porque não consegui fazelo funcionar aqui.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6pco4om7/283/)

Como vcs podem notar, a formatação tem que ficar igual ao

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito grato.

Pensei em alterar algo no projeto, mas não sei o que devo fazer. Segue o link do código do projeto.

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.mask.js

Comment: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/125

Comment: ja tinha visto o site, porem eles estão com o mesmo problema que eu, o - funciona, porem o numero não e formatado

Comment: Eu sei, eu coloquei o link do issue para você ver [o autor do projeto](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/125#issuecomment-37229894) dizendo que esse plugin não foi projetado para isso, e não é possível resolver o problema com o motor que eles desenvolveram de forma sustentável. O próprio recomenda usar outro plugin para permitir números negativos. [Recomendaram](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/125#issuecomment-39099283) o maskMoney.

Comment: entendi. bom ja estou testando ele aqui, sé não sei como limitar o tamanha máximo de dígitos permitido, vc sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Recomendo utilizar o plugin [jQuery maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) , esse plugin vai lhe permitir fazer exatamente o desejado de forma simples e equivalente.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(function() {

  $("input").maskMoney({
    allowNegative: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    affixesStay: false
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: entendo, não a outra forma de resolver o problema do  jQuery-Mask-Plugin?

Comment: Você pode customizar o plugin mais vai exigir uma serie massiva de modificações. Inclusive o Query maskMoney é um fork do maskedinput modificado para propositos númericos. Não tente recriar a roda :)